# How to read plant pictogram instructions?

Tags: optimal-conditions

I bought a plant (I think a [Echinocactus grusonii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echinocactus_grusonii)), which came with pictograms as instructions:

[image: image with pictograms]

For most of them I can make some educated guesses:

- [image: pictogram] small amounts of water
- [image: pictogram] indoors
- [image: pictogram] outdoors
- [image: pictogram] low light conditions
- [image: pictogram] sunny conditions
- [image: pictogram] minimum temperature
- [image: pictogram] maximum size

But what about:

- [image: pictogram] Could be a calender with a water bottle? So only water the plant in march and april?!
- [image: pictogram] Could be a calender with a bloom? So the plant blooms from march to august?
- [image: pictogram] Something about the height

Answer (score 2):

I think it means;

1. Water every 3-4 weeks
2. Blooms for 3-8 weeks
3. It gets taller than it gets wide

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to look up *Echinoccactus grusonii* on a horticultural source to see what the care instructions are. I have no idea what the final pictogram might mean, doesn't make any sense to me, but according to the RHS https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/6253/i-Echinocactus-grusonii-i/Details, this plant gets between 0.1 to 0.5 metres tall, with a width of 0.5 to 1 metre wide - which obviously means it's wider than it's tall, and more or less fits with the pictogram you thought meant height and spread - it clearly does. As for watering, it should be watered as necessary during the growing season, but not at all while its dormant. These don't flower till they're mature, but when they do, it's during summer, usually. In terms of light requirements indoors, a south or west facing window, so that it gets either full sun or half a day's sun.